# what does "per annum OTE" mean?

Tags: salary, job-description, salaried-pay, sales

I came across a "customer service and sales adviser" job vacancy (which is supposed to be direct marketing) online, and for the pay it says "From £15,000 to £25,000 per annum OTE". does this mean I get a basic salary ranging from £15,000 to £25,000 with commission (OTE) included, or does it mean it's commission only.

Comment: Surely this is answered on [What does “Salary plus OTE” mean?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12971/what-does-salary-plus-ote-mean?rq=1) while the question whether it's salary or salary + OTE is something only the company can answer?

Comment: Good rule of thumb for OTE is that (a) you won't make target, and (b) if you do make target, you won't make it again (because the target will go up). If it is commission only ("don't sell, don't eat") then be very careful

Answer (score 2):

On Target Earnings

You will be set a sales target, with commision. If you hit your target, this is what you will earn. You will probably get £15k salary with the rest as commission.

In reality, with an OTE of £25k, you'd have to be a god among salespeople to hit that, in which case, this is beneath you

Comment: Unless they want you to front a little bit of your money for this amazing online opportunity in which case it means something totally different akin to winning a Nigerian lottery.